# Google Sheets: Add specific color to events of same calendar based on partially included abbreviation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Not the cleanest code but does what it needs to - it creates events for social media content in my calendar all tagged with stuff like FB: Customer1 - Post1 or IG: Customer2 - Post1. I now want to give FB  a blue color and IG red, how would that work? I tried it with only one but the code didnt really work this time nor created a colorful entry in my entry.

```
const calendar= CalendarApp.getCalendarById("#######");

function createMultipleEvents() {
  const ws=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss=ws.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=3;i<=ss.getLastRow();i++) { 
    const startingDate = ss.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
    const endingDate = ss.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
    const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 16).getValue();
    
    if (eventName && startingDate && endingDate) {  // Added
    if (calendar.getEvents(startingDate, endingDate, {search: eventName}).length == 0); {

 if (eventName = "FB" ) {




    calendar.createEvent(eventName, startingDate, endingDate);
    event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.BLUE);      
    }

        }
  }


  }

}
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I think that in your script, if you want to compare the value at the if statement, `if (eventName = "FB" ) {` should be `if (eventName == "FB" ) {`. And, in your script, `event` is not declared. But I'm not sure about the value of `eventName`. In your Spreadsheet, the cells "M3:M" are only `FB` and `IG`? Can you provide the sample values of `eventName`?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, it's an honor to receive feedback from you, your comments in the past helped me so much trying to create this, thank you so much! I will post some more information below.

Comment: I added the missing '==' but unfortunately, the events are still not popping up anymore. The cells M3:M are containing the event names like- 
Upload: ALM customer4 - Title
IG Post: AP customer1 - Title2
IG Post: AP customer2 - Title3
FB Post: ALM customer3 - Title1

The sheet itself:

An issue I might see with this is that the table where this information is taken from is continuously updating using =filter({A2:A;D2:D;G2:G;J2:J},{A2:A;D2:D;G2:G;J2:J}) and =filter({B2:B;E2:E;H2:H;K2:K},{B2:B;E2:E;H2:H;K2:K}) for the time and =INDEX(IF((IFNA(O3:O))=0,,IFNA(O3:O))) for the event names

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Your English is great and thank you for your help already. I would like to automatically add colors to the calendar entries based on keywords that are in the name (eventName) of the entry. For example, if the automatically created calendar entry contains the word "FB", then I'm trying to assign a blue color to all entries that are created with the word "FB" in the name. If the entry contains "IG", then all newly created entries with this abbreviation should automatically get a green color. I could also add screenshots for easier understanding if it would help?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you wanted to change the event color for the event title. But I cannot understand the relationship between your script and your Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, in your script `calendar.createEvent` is used. You want to create new events? Or you want to update the existing event?

Comment: And also, I cannot still understand `An issue I might see with this is that the table where this information is taken from is continuously updating using =filter({A2:A;D2:D;G2:G;J2:J},{A2:A;D2:D;G2:G;J2:J}) and =filter({B2:B;E2:E;H2:H;K2:K},{B2:B;E2:E;H2:H;K2:K}) for the time and =INDEX(IF((IFNA(O3:O))=0,,IFNA(O3:O))) for the event names`.